# Vowels are not being detected?

Tags: java, string

How to find a vowel in a given word?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner a =new  Scanner(System.in) ;
        String x=a.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0;i<x.length();i++)
        {
            if(x.charAt(i)=='o');
            System.out.println("the word has a vowel o");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens your string contain more than one vowel? Did you want to print only the vowels present in a string?

Comment: I don't think you're using the `if` statement properly.

Comment: when i give input lets say jdbc it shows thisjdbc
the word has a vowel o
the word has a vowel o
the word has a vowel o
the word has a vowel o

Answer (score 2):

The reason for getting this output is *"when i give input lets say jdbc it shows thisjdbc the word has a vowel o the word has a vowel o the word has a vowel o the word has a vowel o –"* , your if statement is wrong.

When you give semi colon after the if statement, it means you are executing a empty statement.You can either remove the semicolon after your if statement 
( if(x.charAt(i)=='o'){-----}) or try the below solution

I have slightly modified your code to capture and print all the vowels present in the given String.
Hope below code helps -:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner a =new  Scanner(System.in) ;
        String x=a.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0;i<x.length();i++)
        {
            if((x.charAt(i) == 'a') || (x.charAt(i) == 'e')  ||(x.charAt(i) == 'i') || (x.charAt(i) == 'o') || (x.charAt(i) == 'u')) {
                System.out.println("the word has a vowel -: "+x.charAt(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your if statement so it covers the print and break:

```
if(x.charAt(i)=='o') {
    System.out.println("the word has a vowel o");
    break;
}
```

Note that as soon as it detects the first letter 'o' it breaks.